# React Router V6 UseContextApi doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, router

I am trying to pass data form one component to other by useing  UseContextApi and update state value another componant but unfortunatly it's doesn't work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAQjU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrEXB.jpg)

Comment: You've mixed up the order of `[login, setLogin]`. What's the error? you're getting?

Comment: Don't use code images, paste the actual code here. With any errors that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

In context provider, you just need to pass ANY value. In your case you want to pass a state as the value, and that's OK.

The `{value, setValue}` is just for destructuring the return value of useState. So just using `{login}` in the `ContextProvider` may help, instead of `{login, setLogin}`.